# please give me what commands i have to use from moving folders from one server to another server

Tags: command-line, server

We are using ubuntu server, and I have to move folders from one server to another server:

> **Folders:** `/var/www/html/demo5/site/app` to `/var/www/html/1/10/site`
>   
> (Where `app` is the folder name)
>
> **Hostnames:** `123.123` to host `456.456`
>
> **Usernames:** `abc`    to username : `xyz`

I have SSH access, but I am new to these commands.

I have already tried [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69411/remote-linux-server-to-remote-linux-server-dir-copy-how), but I didn't get it to work as I am new to commands.

Comment: Could you give us the commands you tried?

Comment: sorry, i gave wrong username . it worked fine, thanks......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use secure copy (`scp`) :

1. Connect to your `123.123` host with ssh.
2. From here run :

   ```
    scp -r /var/www/html/demo5/site/app xyz@456.456:/var/www/html/1/10/site
   ```
3. (Optional) If you want a move,not a copy, delete the folder :

   ```
    rm -r /var/www/html/demo5/site/app
   ```

---

Refer to [rcp man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man1/netkit-rcp.1.html) for more information.

Comment: it asked for password , i gave correct password, with the same password i am connecting to filezilla,

 but it showing Permission denied.

Comment: You gave the ssh password ? Not he ftp password?

Comment: no, i gave ftp password.... is both are same ?

Comment: No they are not the same, you need to put your ssh password. Do you know it ?

Comment: when we login to ssh, it ask for root and password, i login with the same password.

Comment: You can connect fine to 456.456 in ssh ?

Comment: yes, i can connect to 456.456 ssh , that password only i gave .....

Comment: sorry, i gave wrong username . it worked fine, thanks......

Comment: Great, glad it worked for you.

Answer (score 5):

To copy files from a local machine to a remote machine, do something like this:

`rsync -avz --delete /path/to/local/dir/ remote_user@remote_host:/path/to/destination/dir`

**(Notice that the command uses a trailing slash in `/path/to/local/dir/`, which you DO NOT need in `/path/to/destination/dir`)**

After you've verified that everything worked correctly, delete the source files if you don't need them anymore.

If you don't have `rsync` installed, install it first with:

`sudo apt-get install rsync`

**Rsync is the right tool for the job.** It is very robust, can efficiently continue an interrupted copy job, and the command above will preserve the file attributes and permissions. To additionally preserve hard links, ACLs, and extended attributes, use `rsync -aHAXvz`.

Comment: i have to copy files, i will try now....

Comment: it asked for password , i gave correct password, with the same password i am connecting to filezilla,

 but it showing Permission denied.

Comment: Can you log into the remote machine **via SSH** with this password? `ssh remote_user@remote_machine`

Comment: @profile111 Please see the updated command in my answer. I added a trailing slash in `/path/to/local/dir/`

Comment: sorry, i gave wrong username . it worked fine, thanks......

Comment: Glad it helped.

Answer (score 1):

You probably just have to SSH to the first one beforehand - so after running `ssh abc@123.123` (with actual username and IP address), you could run *something like* one of these (you probably shouldn't do both):

```
scp -r /var/www/html/demo5/site/app xyx@456.456:/var/www/html/1/10/site
rsync -auv -e ssh --progress /var/www/html/demo5/site/app xyx@456.456:/var/www/html/1/10/site
```

Note that this will likely *copy* files. Before running any commands I would recommend backing up your current setup in case anything goes wrong.

If you want more information, you can read the manual pages of various commands using the `man` command - e.g. `man scp`, `man rsync`. I would also recommend looking at what options you are using before doing anything.

<sup>N.B. Not sure but it may be easier to have one server redirect requests to the other if you just want both servers to show the same thing, unless of course you need multiple copies available.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

If you have ssh access you could use `scp` command.

```
scp -r abc@123.123:/var/www/html/demo5/site/app zyz@456.456:/var/www/html/1/10/site
```

I get this information from here: http://www.hypexr.org/linux_scp_help.php

Comment: it asked for password , i gave correct password, with the same password i am connecting to filezilla,

 but it showing Permission denied.

Comment: you should give the abc user or zyz user password. The same password you use to ssh to those host

Comment: when we login to ssh, it ask for root and password, i login with the same password.

Comment: I don't remember what password it ask first, maybe you have to use xyz password first?

Comment: we gave same password for all, i used that one also but still permission denied

Comment: Could you post the command you use when you correctly ssh to host 123.123, please?

Comment: i am using putty software , i am just entering the username and password to connect

Comment: sorry, i gave wrong username . it worked fine, thanks......